# Xdebug ignores me

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have Xdebug 3.1.1 and PhpStorm 2021.3.

php.ini:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=D:\Wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.0\zend_ext\php_xdebug-3.1.1-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Debug port in PhpStorm is 9003 and server is localhost.

When I start my PHP script and listen ports in PhpStorm nothing happens and Xdebug does not return any value. In debug window I see "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'". But when I debug only local CLI script file (no server) it's working fine.

Comment: Try `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`

Comment: Also check that you have the XDEBUG config in both of the `php.ini` files. Check the one loaded when you use `wampmanager->php->php.ini`

Comment: Create a file called `info.php` and add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and share the output specifically for Xdebug.

Comment: Instead of `phpinfo()`, use `xdebug_info()` and it will even tell you whether it tried to connect to your IDE